# Rebuild Boot Setup Bios in efibootmgr

Tags: uefi, bios, efibootmgr

Could you help me? I was trying to get delete an obsolete input from Ubuntu in bios through efibootmgr. I ended up deleting the bios / uefi setup from my samsung laptop and I can not recover it. I typed the command sudo efibootmgr -b 0 -B … (0 being the setup)... Any suggestions?